# $T(M) \cong R<x_1,\ldots,x_n>$ isomorphism question

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, tensors

I have that $T(M) = \bigoplus_{i =1}^{\infty} T^i(M)$ where $T^k(M) = \bigotimes_{i =1}^{k} M$. In a paper i have that to prove such isomorphism, we define:
$$\Phi:R<x_1, \ldots, x_n> \longrightarrow T(M)$$
by the map:
$$\Phi(\sum r_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)}x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}) = \sum r_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}e_{i_1}\otimes\ldots \otimes e_{i_k}$$
but i don't understand what element $\sum r_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)}x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}$ means in $R<x_1, \ldots, x_n>$?. If anyone can explain that to me i will appreciate it. I have no clue on what a polynomial in non-commutative variables looks like.

Comment: A reference to this paper could be helpful to provide some context. Further, from your last paragraph it looks like $R$ isn't commutative; if this is the case, you should make it clear. Also, what is $R\langle x_1,\dotsc,x_n\rangle$? From your tags I would guess a rings of polynomials in $n$ variables, but...

Comment: http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/7752_Spring2010/lecture6.pdf   Thats is the paper, and $R\langle x_1,\dotsc,x_n\rangle$ means the rings of polynomials in the noncommutative variables $x_i$

Comment: I think that $R\langle x_1,\dotsc,x_n \rangle$ is just the free $R$-module generated by the monomials $x_{(i_1,\dotsc,i_k)} = x_{i_1}\dotsm x_{i_k}$ where $(i_1,\dotsc,i_k) \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}^k$, quotiented by the relations $x_{(i_1,\dotsc,i_k)}x_{(j_1,\dotsc,j_k)} = x_{(i_1,\dotsc,i_k,j_1,\dotsc,j_k)}$.